# Random Translations showing up?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-i18n

I have marked text for translation, and also database content with the dbgettext mdoule.

So I do:

```
syncdb
add some content
dbgettext_export
makemessages -l ja
add all of the translations
compilemessages
```

Then I change the /en/ to /ja/ to see the page in japanese, but only two things are translated.

'Yes' and 'No'.

> #Except the displayed 'No' is not even the translation text for 'No'

Nothing else on the page is getting translated.